# How to show category item in its category heading

Tags: php, joomla2.5

I have an array like below

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [cat_id] => 1
            [item_name]=>test1
            [cat_name] => Normal
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [cat_id] => 2
            [item_name]=>test2
            [cat_name] => Featured
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [cat_id] => 2
            [item_name]=>test3
            [cat_name] => Featured
        )  
)
```

And I want the result to look like this

**Normal**

```
test1
```

**Featured**

```
test2  |  test3
```

I have try this so far:

```
<?php
foreach($rows as $row){
    echo '<h2>'.$row->cat_name.'</h2>';
    echo '<p>'.$row->item_name.'</p>';
}
?>
```

But it shows the heading with each of the item.Can someone help me to sort this out.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to group them? Here's a function for that:

```
function groupBy($arr, $func) {
    $groups = [];

    foreach($arr as $item) {
        $group = $func($item);

        if(array_key_exists($group, $groups))
            $groups[$group][] = $item;
        else
            $groups[$group] = [$item];
    }

    return $groups;
}
```

Use it like so:

```
$groups = groupBy($rows, function($row) { return $row->cat_name; });

foreach($groups as $name => $items) {
    echo "<h2>$name</h2>";

    foreach($items as $item)
        echo "<p>{$item->item_name}</p>";
}
```

[And here's a demo.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/tEmPqK) If you don't have the luxury of PHP 5.3, then you can make it more specialized:

```
function groupBy($arr, $prop) {
    $groups = array();

    foreach($arr as $item) {
        $group = $item->$prop;

        if(array_key_exists($group, $groups))
            $groups[$group][] = $item;
        else
            $groups[$group] = array($item);
    }

    return $groups;
}
...
$groups = groupBy($rows, 'cat_name');

foreach($groups as $name => $items) {
    echo "<h2>$name</h2>";

    foreach($items as $item)
        echo "<p>{$item->item_name}</p>";
}
```

[Demo on PHP 5.2.17](http://codepad.viper-7.com/T7rm6y)